# Is "X of Y" a more official statement than "Y's X"?

Tags: possessives, parts-of-speech

For example

the building's history

History of the building

Comment: I don't think that this should be closed as primarily opinion based.  I think that questions about register aren't exactly black and white, but that we can come up with useful answers.

Answer (score 1):

There's no difference in meaning or formality between the usage of **of -possessive** or **s -possessive**.

> the building's history (1)
>
> the history of the building (2)

In (1) the focus is on the building whereas in (2) the focus is on the history.

Yet, there are some debates whether or not the item being referred to with a genitive is human, or an animal, or an inanimate object - in all cases we can use either **of** form or **s** form.

[More on this](https://books.google.fr/books?id=gBegIwquwRYC&pg=PA147&lpg=PA147&dq=possessive+prototypical&source=web&ots=Tz0U_KcDqC&sig=sN0iTE1c5VmqBUc3AwP1DMRFzz4&hl=fr#v=onepage&q=possessive%20prototypical&f=false).