# "X's Y" vs "Y of X"

Tags: possessives, grammar-myths

I remember when I was in junior high school,  my English teacher taught me that

> When the subject is not human nor animal, use **Y of X** to indicate Y belongs to X instead of **X's Y**.

for example

> Use *the book of the library* instead of *library's book*.

But I can find many counter examples, apparently they are not constrained by this rule, so is this rule I was taught in junior high school really a thing? Is there any condition banning *Y of X* or *X's Y*?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using "of" or apostrophe, which is more common?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/65472/using-of-or-apostrophe-which-is-more-common) Also [Is “X of Y” a more official statement than “Y's X”?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/57480/is-x-of-y-a-more-official-statement-than-ys-x)

Comment: That business about not using the Saxon genitive (possessive apostrophe) with inanimate subjects is something learners seem to care about far more than is justified. In practice native speakers rarely allow this to influence their choice. But note that usually for your specific case we'd just refer to *the library book* (with ***library*** used adjectivally as a noun adjunct).